# How to display a specific icon based on the data from a JSON file ? on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-hooks, react-icons

I want to display an Icon regarding on what key inside a JSON file.

```
Example..

JSON file=====>[{
  "name": "Evan Feliza",
  "intro":"Occaecat esse dolor dolor ea eiusmod nulla.",
  "cvfile":"asdsd/asdsad/asdasd//sad",
  "about": "Id eu id in ad aute tempor do voluptate nisi laborum. Do non quis exercitation mollit enim. Adipisicing minim dolor veniam aliqua.",
  "profile":"adasdasdasdas",
  "href":"/resume.pdf",
  "download": true,
  "education":[
    {"course": "Reprehenderit ea ea culpa nostrud.",
    "schoolName":"Commodo ut eiusmod culpa consectetur sit id.",
    "schoolYear": 2000
    }],
  "skills":[
      {"skillName":"html",
      "icons": "<FaJsSquare/>",
      "value":20
    },
    {"skillName":"css",
    "value":20
    },
    {"skillName":"javascript",
    "value":20
    },
    {"skillName":"react",
    "value":20
    }
  ]
}]
```

Problem:  only displays on text and not displaying as a component `icon`.

```
   <section>
      {skillList && skillList.map(skill => skill.skills.map((list,index) =>
        <div key={index} className='drop-shadow-2xl uppercase min-w-md h-full'>
        <CircularProgressbarWithChildren 
          value={list.value}
          maxValue={100}
          styles={buildStyles({style})}
        >
          <div className='flex items-center flex-col'> 
            {list.icons}
            <p><strong>{list.value}</strong>%</p>
            <p className='text-md md:text-lg'>{list.skillName}</p>
          </div>
        </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
      </div>
      ))}
  </section>
```

since it is imported as a Component, i want the json value `string` to turn into a component.

Problem: `key={index}` is not working it still displays this `error`: `react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information. at div`

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem do you have?

Comment: the best thing i did is on put the Icon component inside the JSON file